# How Would I Go About Uploading my local files with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, requirejs

So I have this local website and when I click a button that loads an external js file it says `jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Failed to load file:///G:/JS/Scripts/Code.js?_=1527792497107: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` But that goes away when I use my Golang webserver but then it says local files not allowed. I was thinking about using json to upload the files and get them with http instead of G:/ Is this a good idea?

Comment: You can't acess computer files from the Web Browser, it's a way of protecting the user from malwares. The correct way to acess a file is through a server request.

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP)

Comment: There are various different types of servers and various ways to set them up.  That's a very broad question.

Comment: Your golang webserver allows you to make server requests however your JS file would need to be in the directory your golang server is serving. that way the request can go to your file from the server instead of an arbitrary path on your computer.

Comment: Actually FIreFox allows reading local files with XHR, when the reader document is loaded using file protocol.